# Dynamically created content is updating "a step behind" on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, insert-update

So I am creating a simple question/answer format and having an issue when submitting an answer. I dynamically create divs/buttons/textboxs from the database via a "RenderQuestions()" function. This creates a list of questions and answer textbox/buttons. When attempting to answer a question, I type my answer click submit and nothing happens. I do it again and it shows my first answer. It's a "step behind".. If I refresh it then shows all answers as it should. I've been struggling with this all night. Here's some code:

```
-----My page load----- (Relevant parts)

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //If authenticated hide login & show welcome bloc
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

        //Show question & render
        questionsBloc.Visible = true;
        //if(Page.IsPostBack)
        RenderQuestions();

    }

-----RenderQuestions() function---- (The relevant parts)

        //Initialize & get answers
        List<Answer> answers = new List<Answer>();
        answers = um.GetAnswers(q.QuestionID);

        //Initialize html render
        HtmlGenericControl questionDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        TextBox txtAnswer = new TextBox();
        Button btnAnswer = new Button();

        //Set Answer Button
        btnAnswer.Text = "Answer";
        btnAnswer.Click += new EventHandler(btnAnswer_Click);

        //Set ID's 
        btnAnswer.ID = "btnAnswer" + q.QuestionID.ToString();
        questionDiv.ID = "questionDiv" + q.QuestionID.ToString(); 

        //Set classes
        questionDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "questionBloc");
        btnAnswer.CausesValidation = false;
        btnAnswer.EnableViewState = false;
        //btnAnswer.UseSubmitBehavior = true;



        //Fill inner text with question
        questionDiv.InnerText = q.QuestionContent; //Insert question..
        //actionDiv.InnerText = "Like/Dislike/Comment/Flag"; //Insert answer..

        //Add answer textbox and button to action div
        actionDiv.Controls.Add(btnAnswer);

        //Add question div to qaDiv
        qaDiv.Controls.Add(questionDiv);


        //Add action div to qaDiv
        qaDiv.Controls.Add(actionDiv);

        //Add all controls to feedbloc
        feedBloc.Controls.Add(qaDiv);

-----My btnAnswer event handler -----

private void btnAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    UserManager um = new UserManager();

    um.PostAnswer("My first answer!");
    //RenderGlobalFeed();

}
```

That's every reference to my button.. Should I be initializing the btn click event in my page_init? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoPostBack=true on btnAnswer.  It's not triggering the server to act on the button click.

Comment: How can I do that in the code behind? Set PostBackURL to a redirect page?

Comment: It's triggering the event.. But It's triggering the RenderQuestions() first.. How can I reorder this??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get event `btnAnswer_Click` triggered , then you must render the same Content and assign the eventHandler in every pageload(ie; the page load after the client button click must render the button again and EventHandler must be assigned).

Asp.net won't trigger the event if it doesn't find the controls in the pageload. **Remember, after clicking a button, the page load event triggers first and then only the Click_event will be triggered.**

**The `RenderQuestions()` must be called in the  `btnAnswer_Click` Event too.** This will avoid the a step back problem.

In this scenario I would recommend you to learn about ajax (using jQuery library) requests in asp.net (using WebMethods or webservices) to avoid these postbacks.